# Python unittest: directory and file paths

Tags: python, unit-testing, path

I have the following file structure for a library I'm developing that exposes a keras model:

```
relevancy (repo)
    relevancy (package repo)
        data
            model.h5
            tokenizer.pickle
        test
            __init__.py
            test_model.py
        model.py
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
    setup.py
```

The library basically loads the pre-trained `tokenizer.pickle` and `model.h5` and make predictions on input data.

Within `model.py`, I have a function with the following code that loads the tokenizer and model:

```
def load()
    with open("data/tokenizer.pickle", "rb") as f:
        tokenizer = pickle.load(f)
    model = keras.models.load_model("data/model.h5")
    return tokenizer, model
```

In `test_model.py`, I'm calling this function in my tests.

Then if I call `python setup.py test` under `/relevancy (repo)`, I will get error saying that `data/tokenizer.pickle` is not found. Apparently, the relative is causing the problem.

How should I setup my directory or paths so that the tokenizer and model can always be loaded correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access data files stored inside your package, consider using the [pkg_resources module](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html).

Then in `model.py` you can do something like this:

```
filename = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'data/tokenizer.pickle')
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: This works quite well! Thanks! I just have one more question: I set it like this and I ran `python test_model.py` from `tests` directory, it's showing that the data paths are from the top directory `relevancy/data/tokenizer.pickle` of the library, so it threw me no file or directory error. Is this normal? Is there a solution to make this work at the same time?